# Backup website files using SSH and WGET - omit /path/to/htdocs in resulting tar

Tags: ssh, backup, tar, wget, remote

After SSH into remote webserver, I execute the following command on CentOS remote web server:

`tar -vcf remote_name.tar /home/remote_name/public_html`

On my local sys (Debian based), I execute the following:

```
user@linux-mx21:/var/www/html
$ wget https://example.com/remote_name.tar
$ mkdir remote_name
$ tar -vxf remote_name.tar --directory ./remote_name
```

All good, BUT... I don't want the dir structure the way it results as:
`/var/www/html/remote_name/home/remote_name/public_html/` (public_files,and,dirs_extracted_here).

Instead, I want the result to be as:

`/var/www/html/remote_name/`

where the resulting files under new location,

`/var/www/html/remote_name` would be the mirror of original location, excluding the parent directory structure.

Considering my result w/ commands as illustrated above, the files which now reside in `/var/www/html/remote_name/home/remote_name/public_html` must be moved from to my desired location `/var/www/html/remote_name/`. I want to skip that step with an improvement to my commands.

I presume this can be set w/ args on the `tar` command as desired when I'm SSH at remote_location, but I don't know the correct arguments to achieve what I want.

Your assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tar` has the ability to `chdir` into a directory via the `C` command:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/public_html
$ touch a/b/public_html/index.html
$ tar vCcf a/b/public_html remote_name.tar .
a .
a ./index.html
```

This makes the tarball relative to the current directory
`a/b/public_html`. However, this is not typical, and may be considered
rude, as someone else expanding the tarball will end up by default with
files all over their home directory. If you are the only one using the
tarball, this is probably not a concern.

More typical would be to make the tarball one level up, or:

```
$ rm remote_name.tar
$ tar vCcf a/b remote_name.tar public_html
a public_html
a public_html/index.html
```

Then, on the expansion side you will need to make an appropriate `chdir`
either in the parent command, e.g.

```
cd some/dir && tar xf remote_name.tar
```

or within the `tar` command itself

```
tar xCf some/dir remote_name.tar
```

Exactly what `some/dir` should be will depend on exactly how the tarball
was made, either from the less common `.` directory, or the more typical
parent-of directory.

Comment: Hi. Thank you @thrig 
I'm a bit confused about "are we SSH on remote server, or performing operations on a 'local' server (aka, a server#2)?"
In my example, i'm using remote_name where remote server path is /home/remote_name
and local path is
/var/www/html
(regardless, tarball would remain named remote_name.tar at either location)
I realize you're abbreviating, above. but, E.g. assuming this is SSH on "remote" server, why `$ mkdir -p a/b/public_html` as first command? I realize backups are not usually placed in ./public_html, but for the sake of this example... 
thank you!

Comment: the `mkdir` is so that the subsequent example commands have a directory tree to `chdir` into when constructing the tarball. `a/b` would be substituted for some other suitable directory tree on an actual system